# Setting timeout milliseconds in npgsql

Tags: npgsql

Default connection timeout value of npgsql is in seconds, but I would like to set in milliseconds since I need to have it less than 1 seconds.

p.s. I tried setting fractional(e.g. 0.5) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i have been able to find out you will not be able to use a smaller measurement than a second with that provider, so you are left with few options.

1) Find another provider that allows connection timeout in less than a second.

2) Using a timer throw an exception if the connection was not established quick enough.  I think you will need to use threading techniques for this to work.  I found this guide ‘http://www.albahari.com/threading/’ to be very helpful for me.

3) Use connection pooling and leave a few connections already connected so you don't have to re-establish connection.

good luck

Comment: Thansk Robert, which provider do you recommend for connecting csharp with postgresql?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, i just looked in the manual for the details.  So why do you need to have the timeout so small?  There might be another way to achive your goal.